# Macro failing when I add an extra 'If Like Then' condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that works fine with the 2 conditions in my statement. However when I go to add a third, the macro fails.

Here is the code. This includes the third condition (which is looking for 12212958). If I remove or comment out that line, it runs perfectly. When it fails, debug takes me to that line, and highlights that line.

Why would this be?

```
Sub Clear_Internal_Transactions()
  Dim Firstrow As Long
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim Lrow As Long
  Dim CalcMode As Long
  Dim ViewMode As Long

  With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With
  
  With Sheets("DATA_IMPORT")
    Range("A1:F300").Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlDescending
    
    'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    'Set the first and last row to loop through
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).row
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
    'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
    For Lrow = lastRow To Firstrow Step -1
      With .Cells(Lrow, "C")
        If Not IsError(.Value) Then
          If .Value Like "*12135709*" Then .EntireRow.Delete
          If .Value Like "*12135710*" Then .EntireRow.Delete
          If .Value Like "*12212958*" Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
      End With
    Next Lrow
  End With

  ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .Calculation = CalcMode
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Select Case True
    Case Instr(.Value, "12135709") > 0, Instr(.Value,"12135709")>0, Instr(.Value,"12212958")>0
       .EntireRow.Delete
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

The IF logic is flawed - if a row is deleted on the first or the second IF, the subsequent IF will throw an error as the program already has deleted the row in question.  It's not "the third condition" creating the problem, it's a combination of your data and poor program flow.  You should consider using either `SELECT CASE` or putting your IFs on a single line IF value like OR (a less readable solution):

```
If .Value Like "*12135709*" Or .Value Like "*12135710*" Or .Value Like "*12212958*" Then .EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I can see the flaw in this code now. I grabbed it from somewhere else and adapted it with pretty limited knowledge.